# Gemfile syntax error: when trying bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

// When I try to bundle install --without production                   I get an error message.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: that Gemfile is valid here - I copied it and tried to bundle with it.

Answer (score 1):

This line looks a bit wrong `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'`

Usually you would expect the semantic versioning to go to three levels only

I suspect the problem isn't being picked up when bundling locally.

Comment: No the problem happened when I added development group and production group

Comment: Try this - rename your `Gemfile.lock` to something like `Gemfile.old`, then rerun the `bundle install` command.  If you still get the error, can you share the full error message and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle install` command installs the gems based on the `Gemfile.lock` file in your project. Try running a `bundle update` instead - this may resolve any version conflicts you may be having in your `Gemfile` (depending on if you've made any updates).